# How to split operators and operands into two arrays?

Tags: kotlin

I want to split this content into two seperate arrays numbers and operators in Kotlin.

The content is `"2*5-6+7"`.

This is my code which doesnt work:

```
val arrnum = content.split("[-+*/]").toTypedArray()

val operator = content.split("[0123456789]").toTypedArray()
```

Comment: Maybe post what you were expecting, what went wrong etc? You seem to have just posted some code samples with no explanation of what you want to do/what happened.

Comment: I want numbers and operators in two separate arrays in kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, using [`partition`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html):

```
val OPERATORS = setOf('*', '+', '-', '/')

fun main() {
    val (operators, numbers) = "2*5-6+7".toList().partition { it in OPERATORS }
    println(operators)
    println(numbers)
}
```

Prints:

```
[2, 5, 6, 7]
[*, -, +]
```

Comment: Doesn't work with numbers containing several digits - will split them into digits.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for that, the examples only contain single digits. Hmm but the title says operands, so you could be right. Hard to tell without further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions you have to wrap them into `Regex("[-+*/]")`

The full example would look like this:

```
val arrnum = content.split(Regex("[-+*/]")).toTypedArray()
val op = content.split(Regex("[0123456789]")).toTypedArray()
```

Other things to note: "operator" is a keyword in Kotlin. You can simplify `[0123456789]` to `[\d]` (with double \ in Kotlin). The operator array will contain empty entries for what's left of of the two and right of the 7. You can filter them out like `.filter { it.isNotBlank() }`

Comment: Thanks alot..it works but operators array contains null element in it

Comment: can you post answer with .filter along with code?

Comment: what will the resulting arrays be for "1+2+33+4"? Btw, you can also do `"[etc]".toRegex()`.

Comment: How to remove null elements from the array operators:{"","*","+","-",""} in KOTLIN

Comment: @vichu See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without regular expressions, but with mutability:

```kotlin
const val OPERATORS = "*+-/"

fun main() {
    val s = "2*55-6+7"
    val numbers = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val operators = mutableListOf<Char>()

    var prevIndex = 0
    s.withIndex().forEach { (index, c) ->
        if (c in OPERATORS) {
            operators.add(c)
            numbers.add(s.substring(prevIndex until index).toInt())
            prevIndex = index + 1
        }
    }
    numbers.add(s.substring(prevIndex).toInt())

    println(operators)
    println(numbers)
}
```

Solution without regular expressions in functional style:

```kotlin
const val OPERATORS = "*+-/"

fun main() {
    val s = "2*55-6+7"

    val operatorsIndexed = s.withIndex().filter { it.value in OPERATORS }
    val operators = operatorsIndexed.map { it.value }
    val numbers = listOf(-1, *operatorsIndexed.map { it.index }.toTypedArray(), s.length)
        .windowed(2)
        .map { (from, to) -> s.substring(from + 1 until to).toInt() }

    println(operators)
    println(numbers)
}
```